# solr search by fq is matching partial string

Tags: solr

I set up a Solr instance with some documents already indexed. I want to use filter query to query for certain documents by its url field. The q field is fed the wild card string, and the fq field is given the full url string.

```
q=*:*
fq=url:'mysite.com'
```

This query returns all documents that match url:com.

So any domain that ends in dot com is returned.

How do I get it to return only whole string matches, meaning documents in the domain mysite.com?

Comment: My guess is that your `url` field in your Solr collection is of type `text` (or similar) and not of type `string`. The latter is what you want to use for exact matches.

Comment: quotes around the URL value should work. How is `url` field tokenized, index and query time?

Comment: @DavidFaber in my case I would not use string as I would want to match `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com`

Comment: I would try enclosing the search term in double quotes `"` and using a space instead of a period `.` -- e.g., `fq=url:"mysite com"`. The difficulty I see is that it may still use stemming so that search term might match e.g., `mysites.com`.

Comment: @sidgate, true, but the OP didn't mention partial matches, only "whole string matches".

Comment: url field is declared as <fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>     "mysite com" works. 'mysite com' returns the correct set plus 3 irrelevant docs with no relation to 'mysite'. How bizzar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double quote is the fix.

"mysite.com" gives the right results.